# Inserting records via Loaders in android

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, android-loader

This question would be a follow up from the one asked [Content Resolver vs Cursor Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131058/how-to-properly-insert-values-into-the-sqlite-database-using-contentproviders-i)
Where the answer clearly states how to insert records into a sqlite Db using a Content Resolver . My question is the following :

1. Can i use a loader(Normal Loader) to implement this functionality ?

eg :

```
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
            switch (id) {

    case AppConstants.LOADER_ADD_FAV_PHONE_NUM:

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.TM_DB_COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER,
                directionOrder);
        values.put(TransitMeDBHelper.TM_DB_COLUMN_NAME_ID, selectionArgs[0]);
        Uri insertFavStop =getContentResolver().insert(TransitMeContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_INSERT_FAV_PHONE,
                        values);
        break;
    }

return null;
}
```

Would this run the functionality in the Main UI thread or a worker Thread . I understand that i would not receive callbacks for this as the content resolver will return a URI instead of the cursor containing data .

I tried running this code but it behaves kind of wierd .. Duplicate inserts are recorded and its not consistient , Could someone show me to some right resource which uses a Loader to do Insert operations ( I have seen many examples with query examples and it works like a charm :) )

Thank you for your time .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can i use a loader(Normal Loader) to implement this functionality ?

You can't use a default `CursorLoader` to insert data. If you implement your own `Loader` you could *probably* use the `loadInBackground` method to do the insert but that will make your code awkward at best(and I don't know if it will actually work).

> Would this run the functionality in the Main UI thread or a worker
>   Thread . I understand that i would not receive callbacks for this as
>   the content resolver will return a URI instead of the cursor
>   containing data .

The loader callbacks will run on the thread where they are implemented(the UI main thread most likely) so you're doing the `getContentResolver().insert()` on the main UI thread with the possibility of blocking the main UI thread.

> I tried running this code but it behaves kind of wierd .. Duplicate
>   inserts are recorded and its not consistient ,

Have you tested how many times is the `onCreateLoader` method called?

> Could someone show me to some right resource which uses a Loader to do
>   Insert operations ( I have seen many examples with query examples and
>   it works like a charm :) )

Don't use/try to use a `Loader` to insert data in the `ContentProvider`/Database. It works like a charm for queries because the loaders were designed to load data from a data source(not insert data), that is their purpose. If you want to insert data use an `AsyncTask`(also have a look at [`AsyncQueryhandler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html)), a regular thread.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply .. Yes i tried running with the normal cursor loader but returning null instead .. and it calls the onCreateLoader twice .. ( Also i noted that if i restart a loader it would crash since im returning null the previous call )  . I did not want to use the Async Task because it would react to config changes . Thank you for pointing me to the AsyncQueryHandler .. Then ideally is a cursor loader used only for Querying the data and none of the other C-U-D operations ?

Comment: @Chris *Then ideally is a cursor loader used only for Querying the data and none of the other C-U-D operations ?* Yes, use a `Loader` only to retrieve data from the provider/database or whatever data store you have. If I'm not mistaken, you can't return `null` from `onCreateLoader` so your code will fail. Also the `LoaderManager` takes care of the `Loader` data(for example the `Cursor`) to keep it in a valid state across configuration changes or data updates so those callbacks methods could be called more times then you want.

Comment: Thank you and i am assuming since the AsyncQueryHandler is extended from the Handler class it is not susceptible to config changes like a normal AysncTask or a Thread . This just makes the code little harder to maintain . But thank you for your response .. Im going to implement AsyncQueryhandler as per your advice .