# Android: Using a Loader to make http request, update SQLite database & populate GridView fragment

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

In my Android app, I am making a http request, getting some data, putting it in my local sqlite database & then populating a gridview using that data. I have the code working for an activity but I need to use fragment now to get this done as there are many similar pages to be shown. I read that using Loader is the best way to deal with data in a fragment.

I am not sure about:

1. Whether to use CursorLoader, Async taskLoader or SQLiteLoader(developed by commons guy).
2. In which of the loader functions (onCreateLoader(), onLoadFinished() etc.) do I put my code for making http request, populating the local database & getting the data displayed in a gridview in my fragment
3. I am also using a lazyload list to show images. How will that fit into the entire thing if I use loader

Can anybody help me with this one? Tried searching for good examples or tutorials but I haven't really found something that's really useful. So, please suggest any if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whether to use CursorLoader, Async taskLoader or
>   SQLiteLoader(developed by commons guy).

`CursorLoader` is for `ContentProviders`(which is not your case) and `AsyncTaskLoader` is the way to go. I haven't use the classes from Commonsware but if they allow overriding of some of their methods then I guess you can use it.

> In which of the loader functions (onCreateLoader(), onLoadFinished()
>   etc.) do I put my code for making http request, populating the local
>   database & getting the data displayed in a gridview in my fragment

In none of those callbacks because they run(most likely) on the main UI and you must not do network operations in there. The `Loader` subclasses have the `loadInBackground` method which runs on a background thread. On this method the `Loader` queries for data and in which you could place your networks requests and database updating. But you would need to be *very careful* to not insert duplicate data in the database.

> I am also using a lazyload list to show images. How will that fit into
>   the entire thing if I use loader

As I haven't seen your code, I don't think this two parts are connected. I'm guessing that you use the lazy image loading code directly in the `GridView`'s adapter.

My advice is to not use Loaders for loading **and** inserting data because their purpose is to only load data on a background thread(having taking care of configuration changes). For your particular situation I would make my own `AsyncTaskLoader`(or use Commonsware's library) which queries the database for new data. I would then start a new `AsyncTask` to do the http request and to insert data in the database and then I would trigger a `Loader` restart in the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask`(with `getLoaderManager().restartLoader...`). Have a look [at this similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571805/inserting-records-via-loaders-in-android/13572393#13572393) question for some problems related to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation. I think the approach which you have suggested would be much better for me. I ll try this out once..