# How can I create Cursor based List<MRule> to fill in ListView with MRule.name?

Tags: android

I know I can use Cursor c=managedQuery(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC") to get a Cursor.

Now I hope to get a Cursor from myMRuleList, how can I do? Thanks!

```
lv = getListView();
Cursor c=managedQuery(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");    
String[] cols=new String[] {Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
int[] views=new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,c,cols,views);
this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);

List<MRule> myMRuleList=new ArrayList<MRule>;
MRule aMRule=new MRule();
aMRule.ruleID=1;
aMRule.name="a";
aMRule.enabled=false;
MRule bMRule=new MRule();
bMRule.ruleID=1;
bMRule.name="b";
bMRule.enabled=false;
myMRuleList.add(aMRule);
myMRuleList.add(bMRule);

public class MRule {
  public int ruleID;
  public String name;
  public Boolean enabled;

}
```

Comment: you should have a look at some recent tutorials like [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) because `managedQuery` is no longer recommended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't create a `Cursor` from a `List`. If you want to insert/update the data on permanent storage you should use the `insert()` and `update()` provided by `ContentResolver.insert()/update()` or `SQLiteOpenHelper.insert()/update()` if dealing with `ContentProviders` or SQLite databases respectively

`Cursor`s are typically used with table-like structures (`ContentProvider`s/Databases) not `List`s.

As zapl recommended you should avoid `managedQuery()` and use the `Loader` framework. By doing so, your queries will be done on a separate `Thread`.

Comment: MRule is a business object, I have get the list from database, now I hope to fill the business object into ListView

Comment: And more, I think new ArrayList<MRule> just like  table-like structures , I hope to fill data into lv = getListView();

Comment: Thanks! I hope to fill in ListView with MRule.name

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that? Is it to update your database or what do you want to achieve?

Here is the link to google's reference for the Cursor class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

If you just want to update your database read this SO question:

[How to properly insert values into the SQLite database using ContentProvider's insert() method through a CursorLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131058/how-to-properly-insert-values-into-the-sqlite-database-using-contentproviders-i)

Comment: Oh! I just did not see Emmanuel's answer - as it was edited the last few minutes :). Maybe the links give little help.

Comment: MRule is a business object, I have get the list from database, now I hope to fill the business object into ListView

Comment: Don't really know what you mean exactly. This blog shows how to insert data from databases into ListViews:[link](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.de/2011/02/listview-of-data-from-sqlitedatabase.html)

Comment: Thanks! I hope to fill in ListView with MRule.name

Answer (score 0):

`android.database.MatrixCursor`, is this what you want?