# AsyncQueryHandler bulk insert

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bulkinsert, android-contentresolver

I want to run my Content Resolver operations (query, insert, delete) in a background thread.

I found out the AsyncQueryHandler could solve my problem. The problem with AsyncQueryHandler is: bulk insert. I have this kind of operation in my app, and in the AsyncQueryHandler class doesn't have a bulkInsert method to be overwritten.

How could I handle bulk insert when dealing with AsyncQueryHandler? Is there another option besides the AsyncQueryHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, I changed my architecture.

I removed the bulkInsert and made a interation over the Content Values array. This way I can use the AsyncQueryHandler without problems.

After thinking and thinking, I concluded this is the best option for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use CursorLoader in this case. This will query content resolver and returns a cursor. it uses AsyncTaskLoader to perform the cursor query on a background thread so that it does not block the application's UI.
you can look at http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-android-cursorloader-example for more details.

And you can define bulk insert method into your content providers like below

```
@Override
public int bulkInsert(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull ContentValues[] values) {
    //mOpenHelper is object of helper class.
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();


            db.beginTransaction();
            int rowsInserted = 0;
            try {
                for (ContentValues value : values) {

                    long _id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, value);
                    if (_id != -1) {
                        rowsInserted++;
                    }
                }
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }

            if (rowsInserted > 0) {
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            }
            return rowsInserted;


}
```

Comment: The problem with CursorLoader is when I need to make insert and delete operations. I can't use it for these operations.

Comment: you can refer to this link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131058/how-to-properly-insert-values-into-the-sqlite-database-using-contentproviders-i

Comment: I've seen this answer. The guys tells to use the "getContentResolver().insert(Uri, ContentValues);". The problem is: this kind of insertion goes on main thread ui. I need to make insertion on a background thread.

Comment: if you want to run your insertion in background thread then you can use AsyncTask for that.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncQueryHandler` doesn't support `bulkInsert` probably because this method makes no guarantees about the atomicity of the insertions. What does this mean? Well, if `startInsert` fails for some reason, then there is no insertions done. This means you can have either No insertions made, or One insertion made. There are only 2 options. Atomicity is maintained, i.e, if failed the underlying data source remain the same as before.

If `bulkInsert` of 10 items should fail in the middle for some reason, there can be many options: 3 items are inserted or 5 items are inserted. Thus there is no atomicity. This happens when the `ContentProvider` doesn't override `bulkInsert` and ends up using the implicit `insert` multiple times. So after each item is inserted, the transaction is considered successful and the commit is made. This means for 10 items, 10 transactions occur, and if any one fails in between, there is no rolling back to the previous state of the data source. The atomicity of the operation is lost.

But this is bad. What if you own the `ContentProvider` and you have overridden `bulkInsert` and ensured atomicity is maintained. Then you should be able to use `AsyncQueryHandler` to perform `bulkInsert`.  https://github.com/Madrapps/AsyncQuery library does exactly that. It's the same `AsyncQueryHandler` of Android, but supports `bulkInsert`.

Just make sure you use your own `ContentProvider` that could handle `bulkInsert` if you are concerned about atomicity.